# Can I omit "being" with word "after" in a reduced relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, ellipsis, reduced-relative-clauses

> When (being) happy, dogs wag their tails.

As shown above, sometimes word "being" can be deleted.

Does the word "after" work in the same way too?

> After offended, he sued the owner of the store.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The conjunction "when" can easily be used with an adjective, especially one that describes a state, like "happy", "sad", "thoughtful", "distracted", etc.  The meaning is "at or during the time that".

The conjunction "after" can be used with an adjective that describes a state, but in a very specific flow of events - mostly to indicate another state.

> **After red** the fireworks turned purple, then bright yellow.

"Offended" is a state, but the sentence you have speaks of *an event*, not of a state in which "he" was.  For all we know, he still ***is* offended**.  That is why "*after offended*" doesn't work.